# Page inside a folder can't find App_LocalResources

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using App_LocalResources on my project without problems, that was until i created a aspx page inside a folder, I created the resx file with the same name as i did for others but when the page is inside a folder I cant call the resources for that page.

The way I call resources is:
bt_name.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("bt_name").ToString();

And the soluction struture for the aspx and resx are:
Solution -> Folder -> Page.aspx
Solution -> App_LocalResources -> Page.aspx.resx

What am I doing wrong?